# Can $\|\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{B}\|_1$ say something about rank of $\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, svd

I am considering two $M\times N$ matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ and am computing $l_1$ distance between them

\begin{equation}
\|\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{B}\|_1=\sum_{m,n}|a_{mn}-b_{mn}|
\end{equation}

**My question is:** if $\|\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{B}\|_1$ turns out to be a small (but not like $\epsilon$ small) then can we say that $\Sigma_{\mathbf{A}}\approx\Sigma_{\mathbf{B}}$ where $\Sigma$ are the singular values of a matrix i-1 $svd(\mathbf{A})=\mathbf{U}\Sigma\mathbf{V}^T$

Comment: In short, the answer is yes.  In other words, the singular values are a continuous function with respect to the topology on the matrices induced by $\|\cdot\|_1$.

Comment: Smaller non-zero singular values means that the minimum distance required to guarantee identical rank is correspondingly smaller.

Comment: can you provide some reference/example. I am not familiar with topology so am not able to understand your first comment

Comment: There should also be some matrix norm bounds out there, e.g. $\|A\|_1\leq \sum_{ij} |A_{ij}| \leq \sqrt{n}\sqrt{tr(A^TA)}$ (maybe?) $=\sqrt{n}tr(\Sigma^T\Sigma)$, (Here I'm using $A$ for your $A-B$.) It's a pretty loose bound even if you manage to clean up all the details, and it doesn't give solid guarantees on rank, but it is a relation.

Comment: So I misspoke with that second comment.  We can find a minimum distance that will guarantee that the nearby matrix will have *at least* as high a rank as the other, though.

Comment: I am more interested in the singular values n not rank. Because if $\sigma_1=1.254$ and  $\sigma_2=0.01$ then rank=2 but contribution from $\mathbf{u}_2\sigma_2\mathbf{v_2^T}$ is really negligible. So effectively its a rank-1 matrix. What do you say? Secondly how do we find this minimum distance that will guarantee this rank.  I am looking for some reading material on this topic. Can you please refer some